# Border of body/container not visible in IE 11

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, border, internet-explorer-11

Border is visble in Chrome and Firefox but not visible in IE 11

I googled it and previously my code was border:2px solid black ; I changed it to border-style and added all the specifics in multiple lines. That did not help.

```
.container{
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[This is how it looks in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnzxF.png)

[This is how it looks in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuDP6.png)

Comment: What kind of style does the body have?

Comment: Its a weird fix but I have had borders disappear in IE and I fixed it by either adding `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to the element depending on what element it was. It is hard to offer better advice without more code to be able to reproduce your issue. This is a hack fix but microsoft will be discontinuing support for IE this year which means you will no longer have to support it as well. Our office is going to throw a party when IE support is officially over :D

Comment: .bodyCore{
 border:1px dotted black;
 padding:40px;
 margin-top:8px;
 margin-bottom:8px;
}

Comment: @jeh It helps. It worked. Thanks. I just wanted to test in 3 browsers lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so glad my comment worked! I was unsure so I posted it as a comment but here it is as an answer so people can accept/upvote:

> Its a weird fix but I have had borders disappear in IE and I fixed it
>   by either adding display:block or display:inline-block to the element
>   depending on what element it was. It is hard to offer better advice
>   without more code to be able to reproduce your issue. This is a hack
>   fix but microsoft will be discontinuing support for IE this year which
>   means you will no longer have to support it as well. Our office is
>   going to throw a party when IE support is officially over :D

Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with your CSS code in IE 11.

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
.container{
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:center;
}
.bodyCore{ border:1px dotted black; padding:40px; margin-top:8px; margin-bottom:8px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="bodyCore">sample text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see in the result below that border is visible with IE 11.

[image]

I suggest you to make a test with this code and check whether it is showing the border or not. If issue persist than try to post the exact HTML and CSS code of that page. We will try to make a test with it to check for the issue.